# NAudio.UWP Record ,Write .wav

Tags: audio, uwp, naudio

I know that NAudio.UWP is a work in progress but the newest release (1.8) does seem to have the ability to write a .wav.

```
    private IWavePlayer player;
    private WaveStream reader;
    private IWaveIn recorder;
    private MemoryStream recordStream;
    private IRandomAccessStream selectedStream;

    private void Record()
    {
       if (recorder == null)
        {
            recorder = new WasapiCaptureRT();

            recorder.RecordingStopped += RecorderOnRecordingStopped;
            recorder.DataAvailable += RecorderOnDataAvailable;               
        }

        if (reader != null)
        {
            reader.Dispose();
            reader = null;
        }

        recorder.StartRecording();

    }   

 private async void RecorderOnDataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs waveInEventArgs)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(waveInEventArgs.BytesRecorded);
        if (reader == null)
        {
            recordStream = new MemoryStream();
            reader = new RawSourceWaveStream(recordStream, recorder.WaveFormat);                
        }      

        await recordStream.WriteAsync(waveInEventArgs.Buffer, 0, waveInEventArgs.BytesRecorded);                      
    }
```

Where/How do you create the Storage file name, path etc? There is no destination param...This is the only code that came with the example.

**Mark if you see this Chrome is blocking the 1.8 code download.

Answer (score 0):

> Where/How do you create the Storage file name, path etc?

It actually depends on your requirements. For example, you could use fixed name and timestamp to named your audio file.

```
var file = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFileAsync("song"+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-DD-hh-mm-ss")+".wav",CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
```

Comment: I know how to create a storage file. How does that file get "initialized" to the wavewriter.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy record stream to a new file stream. For example:

```
 var file = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFileAsync("test.wav");
 using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
 {
       recordStream.CopyTo(stream.AsStream());
 }
```

Comment: I'd rather use the new WaveFileWriterRT, I'll try.

Comment: I did get a wavewriter going. Your method and the writer both create a wobbled, choppy and speedy result.